# Convert NSString to NSDate gives wrong date

Tags: xcode, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have the following:

```
NSString *dtString = @"2017-05-18 13:05:45";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *converted = [formatter dateFromString: dtString];
```

This produces an NSDate with: `2017-05-18 12:05:45 UTC` which is an hour behind. How can I get this to match the string exactly.

Edit:

The issue I am having is that when I do a simple date comparison like:

```
NSDate *inTenMinutes = [formatter dateFromString:@"2017-05-18 14:39:40"]; // NSlog will print this as 2017-05-18 13:39:40 UTC
NSDate *now = [NSDate date]; // Nslog prints this as 2017-05-18 14:30:35 UTC    

BOOL isTenMinsDateEarlier = ([inTenMinutes compare:now] == NSOrderedAscending);
```

It evaluates to YES which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: The date is correct. `NSLog` prints the date in UTC. But in date math / NSCalendar / NSDateformatter your time zone `+0100` is considered.

Comment: How can I print it out correctly?

Comment: Use an (output) date formatter

Comment: Hmm, not so sure about this as in the debugger its appearing invalid too.

Comment: The debugger prints the *description* of the date, that's the same `NSLog` does. An `NSDate` object is a point in time, technically a floating point number, it does not have a time zone. If you want to get a **string** back from the date considering the local time zone use a date formatter.

Comment: Please refer to my edit which explains why I think it doesn't work

Comment: The date formatter considers the current time zone, if you want to compare to raw `[NSDate date]` which has no time zone set the time zone of the formatter to UTC: `formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];`

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks!